# NoClassDefFoundError by switching to another project

Tags: java, eclipse, noclassdeffounderror

I have read a lot of answers here to NoClassDefFoundError, but somehow I could not find one that solves my problem. Maybe I have not enough experience to transform it to my problem.

Anyway, I have a project (imported over git) with a package and lots of helpful functions. There is as well a package with some demos, they work completely fine.

If I now copy one of those demos in my own project, I get the error

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/jfree/data/xy/XYDataset
>       at net.[...]

I think there must be a simple solution, since it runs in the other project.

Thank you for taking your time.

Comment: After copying build your project. if it is gradle do gradle refresh or mvn do mvn clean build

Comment: the project I am referring is a maven project, but the one using it is not... so I can't do a maven clean build. Besides, I did not copy the whole project, I just copied the Code (and included/imported everything necessary )

Answer (score 0):

NoClassDefFoundError in Java comes when Java Virtual Machine is not able to find a particular class at runtime which was available at compile time. For example, if we have a method call from a class or accessing any static member of a Class and that class is not available during run-time then JVM will throw NoClassDefFoundError.

- The class is not available in Java Classpath.
- You might be running your program using jar command and the class was not
  defined in manifest file's ClassPath attribute.
- Any start-up script is overriding Classpath environment variable.
- Because NoClassDefFoundError is a subclass of java.lang.LinkageError
  it can also come if one of its dependency like native library may not available.
- If you are working in J2EE environment than the visibility of Class
  among multiple Classloader can also cause
  java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError, see examples and scenario section for detailed discussion.

Comment: Thank you, I checked the 1st point, even adding the class folder to the libraries does not solve the problem. 2nd I do not really understand what to do there... 3rd is not the case. I think 4th sounds promising... If that is what I think - the class I want to use needs a class that I do not have in my workspace? - is that right?

Comment: Yes, There are certain libraries available in the class which you have copied. Those dependency classes are also needed.