# NoClassDefFoundError for com.cloudant.client.api.ClientBuilder but class exists

Tags: java, eclipse, cloudant

Project returns error `Error 500: javax.servlet.ServletException:
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/cloudant/client/api/ClientBuilder`

But class exists.
Error below (removed project's name).
[image]

Here is the dependency

[image]

I've already tried an `mvn clean install -U`, removing the `.m2`
 folder and still no luck so far.

Eclipse version is Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0).

My computer is macOS High Sierra 10.13.6

Comment: Please try maven/update eclipse project and also check whether maven sources are on your path.

Comment: Has the JAR file been deployed to the web container?  Has  the web container has restarted the webapp post the deployment?  Have you checked?

Comment: Updated maven and eclipse project, and neither of these solved. The one thing that solved was deleting the project from disk, download it again with diferent folder name. And yet, after a couple of hours, I got stuck onto the same error.

Answer (score 0):

No class definition found error indicates that your Java runtime could not find the class in question. Please check if your app is deployed to the runtime which you think it should be deployed.

Mostly this would be linked to any of the following steps in you project life cycle.
1. Build (turn on 'build automatically') in Eclipse. I see you've done these steps.
2. Deployment to target runtime (like deploying to some web container). Check if your code is being deployed or not to target runtime.

But I see that you've already mentioned that it works for sometime, which means that you need to understand why the runtime is unable to access your class at that moment. I would do the following.
1. Check if JAR is already present.
2. If not present, follow the build deploy steps you've followed. This means that you'll have to establish how the JAR mysteriously got deleted.
3. If JAR is present, but you see this error, then it means that your runtime CLASSPATH has mysteriously changed and that needs to be investigated. Ideally this should not happen, as all softwares usually are 'consistant', i.e. they either consistently have error or consistently work. This inconsistency itself indicates something environmental which you need to crack.

Is that IBM WebSphere? If this is in your company and it is a shared server or something, check if someone is inadvertently fiddling with your deployment or something.

Good luck!

Edit: Check if this helps you conceptually - [NoClassDefFoundError by switching to another project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56810860/noclassdeffounderror-by-switching-to-another-project)